# Can I send two players to one private server?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game with a friend on roblox called Renze. The matchmaking system should try and match two players and send them to the same server and then deny anyone else from joining that server. The script we currently have teleports the matched players to different server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer 2 players at once into a different server?

Comment: Yea, that’s the problem

Comment: You should make a "portal" where each player could step in and transfer into another server.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I need to get two payers who got matchmade together and nobody else to get sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/TeleportService/ReserveServer
http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/TeleportService/TeleportToPrivateServer

Using these two functions of TeleportService, yes, you can teleport two or more players to a private server using the ReserveServer code returned by ReserveServer.